# When to return value from function, and when to use out parameter?

Tags: c

I'm learning C and programming in general, and I don't know when to return a value and when to use `void`.

Is there any rule to apply when to use one over the another ?

Is there any difference between this two cases? I know that first case is 
working with a local copy of int (n) , and second with original value.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int case_one(int n)
{
    return n + 2;
}

void case_two(int *n)
{
    *n = *n + 2;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int n = 5;
    n = case_one(n);
    printf("%i\n", n);

    n = 5;
    case_two(&n);
    printf("%i\n", n);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: try `case_one(5)` and `case_two(5)`, or `case_two(case_one(5))`.

Comment: It's a design choice with no right/wrong answer. So your question is really just an opinion poll.

Answer (score 3):

There is one more reason to use out param instead of return value - error handling. Usually return value (int) of the function call in `C` represents success of the operation. Error represented by not 0 value. 
Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int extract_ip(const char *str, int out[4]) {
    return -1;
}

int main() {
    int out[4];
    int rv = extract_ip("test", out);

    if (rv != 0) {
       printf("Error :%d", rv);
    };
}
```

This approach used in `POSIX` socket `API` for example.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm learning C and programming in general, and i don't know when to return a value and when to use void.

There is no definitive rule, and **it is a matter of opinion**. Notice that you might re-code your `case_one`  as the following:

```
// we take the convention that the first argument would be ...
// a pointer to the "result"
void case_one_proc(int *pres, int n) {
   *pres = n+2;
}
```

then a code like

```
 int i = j+3; /// could be any arbitrary expression initializing i
 int r = case_one(i);
```

is *equivalent* to

```
 int i = j+3; // the same expression initializing i
 int r;
 case_one_proc(&r, i);  //we pass the address of the "result" as first argument
```

Hence, you can guess that you might replace any whole C program with an *equivalent* program having only `void` returning functions (that is, only *procedures*). Of course, you may have to introduce supplementary variables like `r` above.

So you see that you might even *avoid* any value returning function. However, that would not be *convenient* (for human developers to code and to read other code) and might not be *efficient*.

<sup>(actually you could even make a *complex* C program which transforms the text of any C program -given by their several translation units- into another *equivalent* C program without any value returning function)</sup>

Notice that at the most elementary [machine code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_code) level (at least on real processors like x86 and ARM), everything are instructions, and expressions don't exist anymore! And you favorite C [compiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler) is transforming your program (and *every* C program in practice) into such machine code.

If you want more theory about such whole-program transformations, read about [A-normal forms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A-normal_form) and about [continuations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation) (and [CPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation-passing_style) transformations)

> Is there any rule to apply when to use one over the another ?

The rule is to be pragmatic, and **favor first the readability and understandability of your source code**. As a **rule of thumb**, any [pure function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function) implementing a mathematical function (like your `case_one`, which mathematically is a [*translation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_%28geometry%29)) is better coded as returning some result. Conversely, any program function which has *mostly* [side effects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect) is often coded as returning `void`. For cases in between, use your common sense, and look at existing practice -their source code- in *existing* [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) projects (e.g. on [github](http://github.com/)). Often a side effecting [procedure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subroutine) might return some *error code* (or some *success flag*). Read documentation of [printf](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) & [scanf](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) for good examples.

Notice also that many [ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface)s and [calling conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention) are passing the result (and some arguments) in [processor registers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processor_register) (and that is faster than passing thru memory).

Notice also that C has only [*call by value*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy).

Some programming languages have only functions returning one value (sometimes ignored, or uninteresting), and have just expressions, without any notion of statement or instruction. Read about [functional programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming). An excellent example of a [programming language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_language) with only value returning functions is [Scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheme_%28programming_language%29), and [SICP](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/) is an *excellent* introductory book (freely available) to programming that I strongly recommend.

Comment: Great summary! A programmer is not complete until he studies a lisp dialect, preferably scheme.

Answer (score 1):

It very much depends on what you want to do, but basically You should use the former unless You have a good reason to use the latter.

Think of the implications of the choices. First, let's think about the way we provide input to function. It is quite often that you provide explicitly constant, compile-time constant or temporary data as input:

```
foo(1);
const int a = 2;
foo(a);
int x = 5;
int y = 5;
foo(x + y);
```

In all of the above cases the source of initial value is not a viable location for storing the result.

Next, let's think about how we may want to store the result. Foremost we may often want to use the result elsewhere. It may be inconvenient to use the same variable to store and then pass input, and to store output. But furthermore, often we would like to use the result immediately. We invoke the function as a part of larger expression:

```
x = foo(1) + foo(2);
```

Rewriting the preceding line in a manner that would use a pointer would require much unnecessary code - that is time and complication that we certainly don't want, when it's not really buying anything.

So when do we actually want to use a pointer? C functions are pass-by-value. Whenever we pass anything, a copy is created. We can then work on that copy and upon returning it, it requires copying again. If we do know that all we want to do is manipulate certain data set in place, we can provide a pointer as a handler and all that is copied is several bytes that store address.

So the former, prevalent way to create functions is flexible and leads to concise usage. The latter is useful for manipulation of objects in place.

Obviously sometimes our input actually is an address, and that's a trivial case for using pointers as function parameters.

Answer (score 0):

The first approach is preferred, where you return a value. The second can be used when multiple values are computed by the function.

For example, the function `strtol` has this prototype:

```
long strtol(const char *s, char **endp, int base);
```

`strtol` attempts to interpret the initial portion of the string pointed to by `s` as the representation of a `long` integer expressed in base `base`. It returns the converted value with a `return` statement, and stores a pointer to the character that follows the number in `s` into `*endp`. Note however that this standard function should have returned 3 values: the converted value, the updated pointer and a success indicator.

There are other ways to return multiple values:

- returning a structure.
- updating a structure to which you receive a pointer.

C offers some flexibility.  Sometimes different methods are equivalent and choosing one is mostly a matter of conventions, personal style or local practice, but for the example you give, the first option is definitely preferred.